# What is the most idiomatic way to intersect n ClosedRange instances in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, java-time

I have a list of `ClosedRange<LocalDate>` instances in Kotlin, and want to compute their intersection. What is the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: The intersection of two `LocalDate` ranges would itself be a range (or empty). You can then take the result and intersect it with another range. For a logarithmic solution, you could combine pairs of ranges (via intersection) until you're left with only a single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
val intersection = listOfRanges.let {
    it.maxOf { it.start }..it.minOf { it.endInclusive }
}
```

Alternatively, and especially if you can only iterate once, for example when you have a sequence:

```
val intersection = ranges.reduce { s, t -> 
    maxOf(s.start, t.start)..minOf(s.endInclusive, t.endInclusive)
}
```

And to generalize it:

```
fun <T: Comparable<T>> Iterable<ClosedRange<T>>.intersection(): ClosedRange<T> =
    this.maxOf { it.start }..minOf { it.endInclusive }

fun <T: Comparable<T>> Sequence<ClosedRange<T>>.intersection(): ClosedRange<T> =
    reduce { s, t ->
        maxOf(s.start, t.start)..minOf(s.endInclusive, t.endInclusive)
    }
```